# Select com coluna específica - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Venho migrando para a Oracle e encontrei uma dúvida.

No SQL Server eu conseguia fazer assim:

```
select coluna, * from tabela
```

Como consigo um resultado parecido usando Oracle 12c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle SQL não permite diretamente o uso do `*` com outra coluna, é preciso usar um `alias` para a tabela nesse caso, conforme abaixo:

```
select tbl.coluna, tbl.* from tabela tbl
```

Comment: Valeu Diego, mandou bem!

Comment: Isso mesmo, maravilha. Obrigado!